# Given n, find how many n-digit numbers are there such that the number has prime digit at prime indices and is divisible by m?

Tags: javascript, algorithm, math, permutation, primes

special numbers are such that the numbers have prime digits (2, 3, 5, 7) on prime indices and non-prime values at non-prime indices. (for example, 15743 - prime indices (2, 3, 5) have prime digits (5, 7, 3)).
How many n-digit special numbers are there which are also divisible by m.

For example, for n=2 and m=2, answer will be [12,42,62,82,92], so 5.

I wrote a backtracking algorithm that finds all such permutations of special numbers, then check if each of those special numbers is divisible by m and return the count. This works for small values of n and m, but the problem has n, m values in the range of 0-500.

```js
var primes = [2, 3, 5, 7]
var nonPrimes = [1, 4, 6, 8, 9]


n = 2 // number of digits
m = 2 //divisor
k = 0 //remainder

function rec(index, temp, count) {
  if (temp.length >= n) {
    if (Number(temp) % m === k) {
      /* console.log(temp) */
      count += 1
    }

    return count
  }
  if (primes.includes(index)) {
    for (num1 in primes) {
      temp += primes[num1];
      count = rec(index + 1, temp, count)
      temp = temp.slice(0, -1)
    }
  } else if (nonPrimes.includes(index)) {
    for (num2 in nonPrimes) {
      temp += nonPrimes[num2];
      count = rec(index + 1, temp, count)
      temp = temp.slice(0, -1)
    }
  }
  return count
}

console.log("number of n-digit special numbers which are divisible by m with remainder k is ", rec(1, "", 0))
```

Comment: Why is this tagged python?

Comment: @DaniMesejo It's a mistake, I'm looking for an algorithm, language doesn't matter.

Comment: Indices are 1-based? Why is 25743 an example of this, when 2 is a prime and is sitting on a non-prime index?

Comment: @trincot corrected. yes, indices are 1- based..

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Since a digit-by-digit recurrence can make them interdependent, solve it for all remainders less than `m` and return the solution for remainder 0. Given a table of counts for "special" numbers that leave remainder `r` when divided by `m`, tabulated up to the `i`th index. Then to tabulate the row for index `i + 1`:

```
(1) Transform the current row of remainders,
each storing a count, multiplying by 10:

  for remainder r in row:
    new_r = (10 mod m * r) mod m
    new_row[new_r] += row[r]
  
  row = new_row
    
(2) Create new counts by using the new
possible digits:

  initialise new_row with zeros

  for d in allowed digits for this ith row:
    for r in row:
      new_r = (r + d) mod m
      new_row[new_r] += row[r]
```

For example, `n = 2, m = 2`:

```
row = [None, None]
# We are aware of the allowed digits
# at the ith row
row[0] = 3  # digits 4, 6 and 8
row[1] = 2  # digits 1, 9
row = [3, 2]
```

(1) Transform:

```
  new_row = [0, 0]

  remainder 0:
    new_r = (10 mod 2 * 0) mod 2 = 0
    new_row[0] += row[0] = 3
    
  remainder 1:
    new_r = (10 mod 2 * 1) mod 2 = 0
    new_row[0] += row[1] = 5
  
  row = new_row = [5, 0]
```

(2) Create new counts:

```
  new_row = [0, 0]
  
  d = 2:
    rd = 2 mod 2 = 0
    
    r = 0:
      new_r = (0 + 0) mod 2 = 0
      new_row[0] += row[0] = 5
    r = 1:
      new_r = (1 + 0) mod 2 = 1
      new_row[1] += row[1] = 0
      
  d = 3:  # Similarly for 5, 7
    rd = 3 mod 2 = 1
    
    r = 0:
      new_r = (0 + 1) mod 2 = 1
      new_row[1] += row[0] = 5
    r = 1:
      new_r = (1 + 1) mod 2 = 0
      new_row[0] += row[1] = 5  # unchanged
      
  row = new_row = [5, 15]
  
[12,42,62,82,92]

[13,15,17,
 43,45,47,
 63,65,67,
 83,85,87,
 93,95,97]
```

Comment: I went through this twice, and still not understanding it. Also, will this work for higher values of n, say 400-500?

Comment: @drWatson feel free to ask for more specific clarifications. The complexity here is O(n * m) so it should easily handle n and m at 500.

Comment: will it be possible for you to code it in python/JS? and will this method work, if I wanted the remainder to be non-zero?

Comment: @drWatson great! Here's code for the example you mentioned, n=2, m=4: https://ideone.com/V19tJA (Note that `k` isn't needed since the row will include tabulation for all remainders.)

Comment: The test cases given might be wrong, or am I missing something here??

Comment: @drWatson did we forget the digit 0 maybe?

Comment: @drWatson with the zero added, I just got 444831933

Comment: YES! Thanks for the help, I most probably failed the test (my backtracking approach only solved 2 test cases), but I wanted to know how to solve this. Thanks again!

Comment: Can I ask how do you come up with solutions like this though? I would have never even thought of this approach no matter how long I tried to solve it..

Comment: @drWatson that's a good question. I learned a lot by reading questions here actually that interested me and trying to solve more as well as learn other people's solutions. This particular method would fall under "dynamic programming."